# chef lightweight provider with a two actions that share same code without duplication

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm writing a chef lwrp that does backup using bup.
so lets say I have this code in provider/default.rb:

```
action :backupfiles do
  # create backup dir
  directory new_resource.backupdir do
    owner "nobody"
    group "nogroup"
    mode "0755"
    action :create
  end

  // some file backup specific code
end

action :backupmysql do
  # create backup dir
  directory new_resource.backupdir do
    owner "nobody"
    group "nogroup"
    mode "0755"
    action :create
  end

  // some mysql backup specific stuff
end
```

So both actions share the code for creating backup dir.

What's the easiest way to create a shared action or similar so I don't have to create backupdir in both :backupfiles and :backupmysql.
I simply want to include the shared code that is same for both actions.

So basically I want this type of layout

- backup - generic stuff that both backup actions use.
- backupmysql - only specific stuff for the mysql backup.
- backupfiles - only specific stuff for file/directory backup.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function outside of your actions which call the common resource. It might look like this:

```
def backup_directory(path)
  directory path do
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode 0755 
    action :create
  end
end
```

Then you can call `backup_directory new_resource.backupdir` within the actions.